# jquery v1.7.1 select() function don't work in IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9

my code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            var textarea = document.createElement('textarea');
            $(textarea).val("abc").select();
            $(textarea).select();
            $("body").append($(textarea));
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

this code can work in chrome and firefox,but don't work in IE9,who can help me,thanks!

**UPDATE:**

error on :

```
$(textarea).val("abc").select();
```

Comment: Try `$(textarea).focus();` after you append it, not before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have more luck if you move the .select() line to AFTER the append() line. Also, try `$(textarea).focus().select();` instead. This works for me in IE8 at least - don't have IE9 handy.

edit: My approach would be something like

```
$(function(){
   var textarea = document.createElement('textarea');
   $(textarea).val("abc");
   $("body").append($(textarea));
   $(textarea).focus().select();
});
```

Comment: Didn't even see that .select() on that line just drop it.

Comment: Just to note, document.createElement isn't very jQuery-like. This could all be chained nicely like this. `$('<textarea>').val('abc').appendTo('body').focus().select();`